# MAMP/WAMP - Switch back from real project URLs to localhost in all my files

Tags: url, localhost, wamp, mamp

Good morning,

does anyone know how I could configure MAMP (or WAMP) in order to automatically change my project URLs, to localhost without having to search/replace inside my documents (operation I suppose to be a bit gross because possibly altering my code).

My goal is to develop on local while keeping the final and real URLs in my documents.I suppose lot of you have encountered this issue one day :)

In other word, I would like to alternate between online and local more easily.

I a beginner, please consider,

Answer (score 0):

for all the biginners, here's the thing. I've created a config.php file which contains constants: one config file for the local project folder and one for the online server folder.

Inside this config file, I've create a constant (constant are then available everywhere in the project) to define the main URL of the project. e.g.:

```
define('CST_MAIN_URL',http://www.myproject.com); // for the online config.php file
define('CST_MAIN_URL',http://localhost:8888); // for the local config.php file
```

Thus, each header or redirection can work with that constant, like:

```
header('location:' . CST_MAIN_URL . 'index.php');
```

Then, things must have to do with RewriteEngine in your htaccess file, for instance whenever you must modify the behavior of MAMP/WAMP if an interrogation point or a slash provokes you with its malicious resistance. But, unfortunately RegEx expression must be understood as a basic level for mastering those url rewritings.

Hope it'll helps.